# File output reads first instance of results correctly, following inputs are incorrect

Tags: c++, file, class, input

so I have a program that makes use of a Registration, UNIT, Result and Date class to store and output some details in a new file. The order is as follows: File is read into registration where some values are stored, and then the rest of the input is sent to an array of objects of results. When it is sent to results, it reads into a UNIT object, then into a variable 'mark', and then to a date object lastly. Once sent to date, the program reads the day month and year, and that is the final input. My output file produces the first set of units correctly, however, after that it is all messed up. Can someone explain where I have gone wrong, I'd imagine in my input syntax/logic? I will only post the .cpp input and output functions for the sake of readability and as everything compiles just fine, but if you do need the .h and .cpp files of all classes let me know. Thanks in advance.

Result.cpp input and output function:

```
void Registration::readFile(istream &input){

    long studentid1;
    unsigned semester1;


    input >> studentid1 >> semester1 >> count;


    SetStudentID(studentid1);
    SetSemester(semester1);


    for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
    input >> results[i];

}

void Registration::writeFile(ostream & os) const{

    os << "Student ID: " << GetStudentID() << '\n'
     << "Semester:   " << GetSemester() << '\n';

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
    os << results[i] << '\n';


}
```

UNIT.cpp input and output functions:

```
void UNIT::SetUnit(istream &input){

  string nam;
  string idd;
  unsigned cred;

  getline(input,nam, '\n');
  getline(input,idd,'\n');

  input >> cred;

  SetName(nam);
  SetID(idd);
  SetCredits(cred);

}

void UNIT::GetUnit(ostream & os) const{

  os << "  Unit ID:  " << GetID() << '\n'
     << "  Unit Name: " << GetName() << '\n'
     << "  Credits: " << GetCredits() << '\n';

}
```

Result.cpp i/o functions:

```
void Result::SetResult(istream &input){

    UNIT unitobj1;
    unsigned marks1;
    Date date1;

    input >> unitobj1 >> marks1 >> date1;
    SetUnit(unitobj1);
    SetMarks(marks1);
    SetDate(date1);

}

void Result::GetResult(ostream &os) const{

    os << GetUnit() << "  Marks: " << GetMarks() << '\n' << GetDate();

}
```

Date.cpp i/o:

```
void Date::SetDate(istream &input){

    unsigned day1;
    string month1;
    unsigned year1;


    input >> day1 >> month1 >> year1;
    SetDay(day1);
    SetMonth(month1);
    SetYear(year1);


}

void Date::GetDate(ostream &os) const{

    os << "  Date: " << GetDay() << " " << GetMonth() << " " << GetYear() << '\n';

}
```

rinput.txt (input file):

```
102234 962 3
Data Structures and Abstractions 
ICT283
3 90 30 June 2016
Applied ICT Research Skills 
BSC250 
3 92 29 April 1993
Games Technology
ICT292
3 76 4 August 1998
```

routputnew.txt (outputfile):

```
Student ID: 102234
Semester:   962
  Unit ID:  ICT283
  Unit Name: Data Structures and Abstractions 
  Credits: 3
  Marks: 90
  Date: 30 June 2016

  Unit ID:  Applied ICT Research Skills 
  Unit Name: 
  Credits: 0
  Marks: 90
  Date: 3395525844  7402640

  Unit ID:  3 92 29 April 1993
  Unit Name: BSC250 
  Credits: 0
  Marks: 90
  Date: 3395525844  7402640

Number of units = 3
Total credits     = 3473594268
```

Comment: Presumably one of your input calls is failing then the steam won't read anything else. You need to check the stream state after each read. If appropriate you can then use clear and ignore to get the steam back to a readable state

Comment: I would like to help you. But then I need the full code, so that I can debug it and give recommendations on how to improve. Put it somewhere and post the link.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Even without seeing your full source code, I will help you.

You have 2 major problems

1. You do not check, if an extraction operation (>>) failed or not
2. You have a problem with the endline charachter after extracting without `std::getline`

So, what will happen. Assume the following simple test program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream testDataStream{ R"(1 2
string1
3 4
string2)" };

int main() {

    int i1{}, i2{}, i3{}, i4{};
    std::string s1{}, s2{};

    testDataStream >> i1 >> i2;
    std::getline(testDataStream, s1);
    testDataStream >> i3 >> i4;
    std::getline(testDataStream, s2);
    // more code . . . 
    return 0;
}
```

First we will read i1 and i2 with correct information. The extractor operator reads until the next whitespace, but does not consume the '\n' at the end of the line. It has read i1 and i2, skipping the white space. Then stop. No more activity. Nothing will consume the '\n'.

If you now call `std::getline` it will start to read after the value 2 and will find a '\n'. Then it stops reading and returns an empty string. So, after the call to `std::getline` the `std::string` s1 will be empty, the '\n' will be consumed and the next position to read from is "string1".

And now we try `testDataStream >> i3 >> i4;`. But there is no 3 and 4. Remember: The position to read is still at "string1". So the extraction operation will fail and the `failbit` of the stream will be set.

But you do never test the `failbit` and so the rest of the program silently fails.

You can and should check the result of each extraction operation.

This can simply be done with

```
if (testDataStream >> i1 >> i2) {
    // Good. Continue standard operation
}
else {
    // Bad. Show error message and do error handling
}
```

Why does this work? The chained extratcion operation returns a reference to the stream at the end. And the stream has an overloaded bool operator. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

So, to test the state of the stream you can write always simply `if (someStream)`.

OK, understood. But how can we get rid of the trailing '\n' at the end of the string. For that we have the function [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). See the documentation in the link.

To fix the avoe code snippet we need to add `ignore` 2 times:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream testDataStream{ R"(1 2
string1
3 4
string2)" };

int main() {

    int i1{}, i2{}, i3{}, i4{};
    std::string s1{}, s2{};

    testDataStream >> i1 >> i2;
    testDataStream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::getline(testDataStream, s1);
    testDataStream >> i3 >> i4;
    testDataStream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::getline(testDataStream, s2);
    // more code . . .
    return 0;
}
```

And to show you, how all this can be implemented, I prepared a full working example for you.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <array>

// Function to check, if we have a valid month
constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 12> Months{ "January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June", "July","August", "September", "October","November", "December" };
bool isInValidMonth(const std::string& m) { return std::find(Months.begin(), Months.end(), m) == Months.end(); }

struct Unit {
    // Data for one semester/class unit for a student
    std::string id{};
    std::string name{};
    unsigned int credit{};
    unsigned int mark{};
    unsigned int dateDay{};
    std::string dateMonth{};
    unsigned int dateYear{};

    // This will check, if the data that we have read is ok, and if not, set the fail bit of the stream
    std::istream& sanityCheck(std::istream& is) {

        // Check for non plausible data. If there is unplausible data anywhere
        if (!is || credit > 500 || mark > 100 || dateDay == 0U || dateDay > 31 || dateYear < 1920 || dateYear > 2100 || isInValidMonth(dateMonth)) {

            // Set the streams failbit
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Problem while reading unit data\n";
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Overide extractor. Get Unit data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Unit& u)
    {
        if (std::getline(std::getline(is, u.name), u.id) >> u.credit >> u.mark >> u.dateDay >> u.dateMonth >> u.dateYear)
            // Eat up the trailing '\n'
            is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        return u.sanityCheck(is);
    }
    // Overwrite inserter. Write unit data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Unit& u) {
        return os << "\tUnit ID:\t" << u.id << "\n\tUnit name:\t" << u.name << "\n\tCredits:\t" << u.credit << "\n\tMarks:\t\t"
            << u.mark << "\n\tDate:\t\t" << u.dateDay << " " << u.dateMonth << " " << u.dateYear << "\n";
    }
};

struct Student {
    // Student data
    unsigned long id{};
    unsigned long semester{};
    std::vector<Unit> unit{};

    // Override extractor: Read Student Data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Student& s) {
        s.unit.clear();
        // Here will store the number of units that we need to read
        size_t numberOfUnits{};

        // Read, id and semester and numberOfUnits and check, if that was successfull
        if (is >> s.id >> s.semester >> numberOfUnits) {

            // Eat up the trailing '\n'
            is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            // Read all units. Call the extractor operator n times, but only if everything OK
            for (size_t i = 0U; i < numberOfUnits && is; ++i) {

                // Read a unit and check, if OK
                if (Unit temp{}; is >> temp) {

                    // If OK, append the new unit to the student
                    s.unit.push_back(std::move(temp));
                }
            }
        }
        // Sanity check. We expect to have numberOfUnits
        if (!is && s.unit.size() != numberOfUnits) {
            // Set the streams failbit
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Problem while reading student data\n";
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Override inserter: Write student data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Student& s) {
        os << "\n\nStudent ID:\t" << s.id << "\nSemester:\t" << s.semester << "\n\n";
        std::copy(s.unit.begin(), s.unit.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Unit>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

struct Register {
    std::vector<Student> students{};

    // Override extractor: Read Student Data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Register& r) {
        for (Student s{}; is && is >> s; ) if (is) r.students.push_back(s);
        return is;
    }


    // Override inserter: Write complete Register
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Register& r) {
        std::copy(r.students.begin(),r.students.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Student>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }

};


std::istringstream inputStream{ R"(102234 962 3
Data Structures and Abstractions 
ICT283
3 90 30 June 2016
Applied ICT Research Skills 
BSC250 
3 92 24 April 1993
Games Technology
ICT292
3 76 4 August 1998
222222 22 2
Data Structures and Abstractions 2
ICT222
3 90 30 June 2016
Applied ICT Research Skills 2
BSC222 
2 2 2 February 1993
)" };

int main() {

    Register r;
    inputStream >> r;
    std::cout << r;

    return 0;
}
```

Have fun . . .